# .net Core 3 , How to load and invoke external a method by name from an external assembly (dll)

Tags: .net, dll, .net-core, .net-assembly, invoke

Is it possible to run a method from a loaded file assembly, knowing only a method name?

I can scan the dll and get all classes and their methods; I want to run a method starting with a specific prefix like `exe_myMethod`
should i get a list of required parameters first?
Any thoughts ? Thank you !

```cs
    var myAssembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(fileName);
    Type[] types = myAssembly.GetTypes();
    foreach (Type t in types)
    {
    if (t.IsPublic)
    {
         dynamic myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
         MemberInfo[] methodName = t.GetMethods();
         foreach (MemberInfo method in methodName)
         {
             if (method.ReflectedType.IsPublic)
             {
                 // invoke method - How?
             }
         }
     }
    }
```

Sorry if it is a stupid question ! :)

Comment: `MethodInfo` has an `Invoke` method.

Comment: looks like it should be like this : var methodInfo = t.GetMethod(mName);
                                if (methodInfo != null) 
                                {
                                    var o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                                    var result = methodInfo.Invoke(o,null);
                                }

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. 
Here is the result.

```
            var myAssembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(fileName);
            Type[] types = myAssembly.GetTypes();
            foreach (Type t in types)
            {
                if (t.IsPublic)
                {
                    dynamic myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                    MemberInfo[] methodName = t.GetMethods();
                    foreach (MemberInfo method in methodName)
                    {
                        if (method.ReflectedType.IsPublic)
                        {
                            string mName  = method.Name.ToString();
                            var methodInfo = t.GetMethod(mName);
                            if (methodInfo != null) 
                            {
                                var o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                                ParameterInfo[] pars = methodInfo.GetParameters();
                                if (pars.Length == 0) // if there is no parameters
                                {
                                    var result = methodInfo.Invoke(o, null);
                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                    object[] MyParameters = new object[] { "parameter" }; 
                                    var result = methodInfo.Invoke(o, MyParameters);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```